# How can i create a good transition for a imagem and center the project?

Tags: javascript, html, css

in my class we have a server where we put all of our web projects, but the main page is the default one, and my teacher asked me to create a "landing place" something like that. Ive created something normal but I want to make it better, i have the normal page with buttons but when i have my mouse over i wanted it to appear a picture of each one of us. Its working but the image just appears with no animation and I cant change it, i cant even center vertically this. I was wondering if someone could help me..

Please don´t judge me, I am new to this and i´m trying to learn.

To center vertically, I literally tried applied all center properties and still didn´t worked.

For the image, I tried a opacity transition and to keep up with the button I tried a translateY 10px to keep it with it.
The white picture is just a test, later I will change it to the real ones.

[normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xemTB.png)

[mouse over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcfeU.png)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>11TGPSI</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">11TGPSI.</div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="line">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 1</div>
                    <div class="name">Afonso Nabeto</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 2</div>
                    <div class="name">Bianca Silva</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 3</div>
                    <div class="name">Duarte Rocha</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 4</div>
                    <div class="name">Guilherme Costa</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="line">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 5</div>
                    <div class="name">Hugo Silva</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 6</div>
                    <div class="name">Joana Rita</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 7</div>
                    <div class="name">João Teixeira</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 8</div>
                    <div class="name">João Ladeira</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="line">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 9</div>
                    <div class="name">Keila Mendes</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 10</div>
                    <div class="name">Leonardo Melendre</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 11</div>
                    <div class="name">Lucas Diniz</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 12</div>
                    <div class="name">Marlom Silva</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="line">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 13</div>
                    <div class="name">Miguel Lourenço</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 14</div>
                    <div class="name">Ruben Magalhães</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 15</div>
                    <div class="name">Tomé Almeida</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div class="number">Nº 16</div>
                    <div class="name">Ygor Mendonça</div>
                    <div class="image"><img src="./images/personIcon.png" height="120"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

            links.forEach(link => {
                link.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                    const image = link.querySelector('.image');
                    image.classList.add('image-active');
                });

                link.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
                    const image = link.querySelector('.image');
                    image.classList.remove('image-active');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:700|Poppins:400');

:root {
    --text: #ebe7e5;
    --background: #0c0a09;
    --primary: #8c9fa6;
    --secondary: #0b0c0e;
    --accent: #64827b;
}

* {
    font-family: Poppins;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--background);
}

.logo {
    color: var(--text);
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.line {
    display: flex;
}

a {
    background-color: none;
    color: var(--text);
    width: 200px; 
    height: 70px; 
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    border: 1px solid;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

a:hover {
    height: 200px;
    background: var(--text);
    color: var(--secondary);
}

.number {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.name {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.image {
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.image-active {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: your teacher probably asked you to create a "landing page" not a "landing place"

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes you are right, it was my bad sorry!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have to suggest you that using add and remove class is no longer a good way to give active styles, instead you can simple use toggle to add/remove class in events.
Secondly, you can chane `transition: 0.8s;` to `transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;` to have a slow start and end.

Comment: what is wrong with removing and adding classes?

Comment: i will try it for sure, thank you so much!!

Comment: @LelioFaieta it's nothing wrong and works well. Using toggle can help you have a better code. For instance, you have to once use addClass and after that removeClass but with toggle you can have both of these methods inside of a line.

Comment: it didn´t worked, can´t i use a keyframe?

Comment: @ToméAlmeida please explain what happened and which part didn't work out? because I suppose your problem is not a single thing

Comment: @mehrb0d its already solved man, i had 2 main problems, center the container and getting an animation on the image but its done rn so its fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center image vertically it is better to change height of the `<a></a>` tag when hovered, to 220px.

```
a:hover {
height: 220px;
background: var(--text);
color: var(--secondary);
```

}[image]

Comment: hello, first of all thank you for your help,the align part is for all the container, i can center it all but i wanted the logo on top left thats my problem :)